# Why some android phone click event system comes with the sound, and some mobile phone click event but no sound

Tags: android

Why some android phone click event system comes with the sound, and some mobile phone click event but no sound.
Is this the reason for the phone system? I set the code in the android: soundEffectsEnabled = "true" there is no sound.

Comment: Because of "Touch Sound" settings in your phone.

Comment: Yes, I ignored the problem